# How to get an item from a RealmList using android databinding

Tags: java, android, realm, android-databinding, realm-list

I have a Car class implemented like this :

```
        public class Car extends RealmObject implements Serializable {
       @SerializedName("car_details")
        @Expose
        private RealmList<CarDetail> carDetails = null;
  public RealmList<CarDetail> getCarDetails() {
        return carDetails;
    }

    public void setCarDetails(RealmList<CarDetail> carDetails) {
        this.carDetails = carDetails;
    }
    }
```

in My trying to access my carDetails  from my Layout like this :

```
<TextView
                                                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="8dp"
                            android:text="@{car.carDetails.get(0).grade}"
                            android:textAllCaps="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="30sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

but i'm getting an error when compiling , any suggestions how to access the list?

i also tried with :

```
android:text="@{car.carDetails[0].grade}"
```

I'm getting an error like this :

```
error: package me.test.databinding does not exist
```

It's cannot generate the databinding classes

Capture from the error:
[image]

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @AyushKhare Error:(14, 39) error: package me.sample.test.databinding does not exist

Comment: Please post the whole error log

Comment: The whole error is just this, simply the databinding can not be generated because my code to get a singel item from the RealmList is wrong , if you know how to get specific items from the list in databinding code please tell me

Comment: That's the correct way to get the list object in your data binding, but the real error is not because of it cannot generate data binding. I cannot help you unless you post the full error log

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33934991/5575410 and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40494338/5575410

Comment: i edited the question, i added a screen capture of the error Log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing you error log screenshot shows the actual problem

> **Your error:**  *com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for rx.Observable not found*

**FIX:**

This can be fixed by either adding RxJava to your project or create an empty dummy file that looks like the following.

```
package rx;

public class Observable {
    // Dummy class required for Jackson-Databind support if
   // RxJava is not a project dependency.
}
```

**Reference:**

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40509944/5575410), [this](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1070) and [this](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#jackson-databind)

Comment: Well it worked with this Dummy Class, Knowing that im using RxJava2 in this project, thank you